# How to get asp.net Session value in jquery method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to access a Session value in jquery method in the ASP.NET MVC view page. See the below code,

```
$('input[type=text],select,input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', '<%= Session["CoBrowse"].ToString() %>');
```

How can I get the Session value in jquery.

Comment: That looks like it should work. What happens when you use the code above?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$('input,select').attr('disabled','<%=Session["CoBrowse"].ToString() %>');
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is the best route but within your aspx page you could create a method that returns the value of your session variable, e.g.

Server side:

```
using System.Web.Services;
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string GetSession()
{
   return Session["CoBrowse"].ToString();
}
```

then call this method client side using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./Default.aspx/GetSession",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
        ('input[type=text],select,input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', result.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you access Session from within a static method?  I didn't think you could.

Comment: This is the route I've gone down aswell. I have a web service that returns me the session id like so.. Guid a = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["Session_Id"].ToString());   and then I read that into the client side via the jquery ajax function. Bare in mind that it will need to be a GET as you are only returning a value.

Comment: I don't know why anybody up vote for this answer. we can't get Session in static method

Answer (score 8):

Many comments:

1. You cannot "Access Session from jQuery". You use MVC and asp.net to create an HTML page (with JavaScript). Session is a server-side object, and JavaScript runs on the client side.
2. Take a look at [jQuery's selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors). They have useful selectors like `:checkbox`, `:text`, etc.
3. Your code produce the JavaScript you expect: it compiles, runs, and produces JavaScript with `true` or `false` on the right place.
4. This is not the way to disable an element. If an element has the 'disabled' attribute it will be disabled, no matter the value. `<input type="checkbox" disabled="false" />` is also a disabled check box, so **your controls are always disabled**.
5. If that is the way you choose anyway, consider:

   ```
   var isCoBrowse = <%= Session["Name"].ToString().ToLower() %>;
   if(!isCoBrowse) //disable controls
     $(":text,:checkbox,:radio").attr("disabled","disabled"); //standard.
   ```

   This will produce the client-side JavaScript code:

   ```
   var isCoBrowse = true;
   ```

   And, to enable an element:

   ```
   $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
   ```

Also, there are much better ways to accomplish this. Have you considered disabling the controls on server side, if possible?

Comment: var isCoBrowse = <%= Session["Name"].ToString().ToLower() %>; wrong syntax

Comment: #1 - Wrong answer (e.g. var search = @Session("MyValue") works)

Comment: @EdDeGagne - Didn't I write that on point 5? JavaScript cannot access the session directly, and does not even know there is a session. Using the session, as server side, to create JavaScript, is something else altogether.

Comment: @Kobi, you can access the Session object in a Razor view in jQuery, I am doing so as I type this. Of course, this is the current client value and not that of the Server object (which I think you were suggesting in point #5).

Answer (score 6):

```
<input id="sessionInput" type="hidden" value='<%= Session["name"] %>' />

var getSessionValue = $('#sessionInput').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

If that Session variable is sensitive data (which in this case it probably isn't), I would not use this solution as it would show the Session data when you looked at the javascript source. If it is sensitive session data, accessing it via a web method (see above answer) is probably best.

Answer (score -1):

Easy! when you know how:

@Html.Encode(Session("classificationTitle"))

...and in the .js file:

```
var classificationTitle = document.getElementById('classificationTitle').innerHTML;
```

sorry - I can't post the full html as this site strips out angle brackets :(